# I dupehammered a question, the OP got nasty... and my comments got nuked

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, declined-flags, dupehammer

I recently dupehammered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861301/equivalent-of-nameof-in-python). The answer is basically "your task only makes sense in certain cases, and here's how you do it in those cases." The OP immediately flipped his lid, questioning in a series of comments the following:

- my reading comprehension skills ("if you had read the question")
- my intelligence ("what can't you understand")
- my knowledge ("maybe your're not aware of")

I patiently explained that the concept he was describing simply didn't exist in the scope he was hoping for, and that the linked duplicate outlined the way to accomplish it when possible. After it became clear that the OP was just lashing out because he didn't like his question being closed (few people do; it implies that the poster didn't do enough research on a basic question), so I flagged the comments with a custom flag and moved on.

I later saw that my flag was declined, none of the abusive comments were removed, and - the kicker - *every single one of my comments was nuked from the question*.

The question was unhammered and rehammered as a duplicate of a similar question, with answers that provide a different but equally unreliable way of accomplishing the task (since the task is technically nonsense in many cases). OP was somehow pleased at this, and took the opportunity to complain about me again.

After that, I browsed my tag of choice and answered a bunch of easy questions that I probably could have dupehammered given varying degrees of dupe research. Instead of getting yelled at, getting a flag declined, and having my comments nuked, I rep capped and enjoyed some appreciative comments.

I don't know that I have a specific question here, but that's what the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) tag is for, and I'm not sure what kind of response I'm looking for, but anything *constructive* and *considerate* would be welcome.

Comment: *"The OP immediately flipped his lid, questioning in a series of comments the following: ..."* Yeah, all of this is totally, 100% normal. People do this to me all the time. The place where you went wrong was trying to patiently engage and explain things to a person who started acting like this. You just dupe-hammer responsibly, and move on. Your job there is done, unless one of the asker's comments legitimately convinces you that you have erroneously marked the question as a duplicate. In that case, you have an obligation to re-open, but still no obligation to respond.

Comment: _"After that, I browsed my tag of choice and answered a bunch of easy questions <...>"_ Dude, don't. ___[Never answer dupes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)___. Especially not when the only reason is _petty revenge_ for a declined flag.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I didn't want revenge, I wanted a pleasant experience. Askers thanked me for my tidy solutions, other users said that my answer taught them new techniques they'd never seen, and I even got rep. It was pretty nice, like a warm blanket after spending a day in the snow. Anyway, I've answered eight questions and cast six close votes in the last day. Not a particularly egregious ratio by most standards.

Comment: It is egregious if those 8 questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Cerbrus - 1. At this point, everything is a duplicate if you look hard enough. 2. None of the questions I answered were closed as duplicates. 3. I said "easy" questions, that I might have been able to eventually find a duplicate for if I spent a lot of effort looking for them and wanted to be shouted at. Which I don't.

Comment: I close questions as dupe all the time and hardly ever "get shouted at". My suggestion: Don't respond to those shouts.

Comment: If you often "get shouted at", I would suggest to pick better duplicates or stay at the page longer to explain why you think your duplicate choice is correct. Not closing unclear questions or questions without proper MCVE as duplicates would help too.

Comment: @vaultah - I don't have a number for the frequency, but it's often enough that I dread it. The response to answering questions is much more positive.

Comment: And I would like to remind everyone of my request for "_constructive_ and _considerate_" input.

Comment: Hang on; @CodyGray says "move on" while vaultah says "stay at the page longer to explain." That doesn't make things clearer for me.

Comment: Hmm, you've had the [python] gold badge for a while now.  Still not getting with the program, the intention of the hammer is to maximize the amount of abuse you get exposed to so you'll stop closing the seen-it-all-before questions.  There is a simple workaround for it, just fake the normal close comment: Possible Duplicate of [Getting the class name of an instance in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python).  Usually good enough in a high volume tag to get the question closed the normal way.

Comment: I know, @Tigerhawk. I'm confused, too. How can someone disagree with me?

Comment: *my reading comprehension skills* - For whatever reason, accusing someone of not reading something, even when that's obviously not the case, is considered a constructive comment. Rather than flagging, I just point out that disagreeing with someone isn't the same thing as misunderstanding and move on. They are trying to pick a fight, you don't have to fall for it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I estimate duplicate to cost ~-30-40 rep for first person that finds duplicate (time spent on search could be used to provide immediate answer)... So with such "positive" reinforcement I'm surprised there are still people VTC as duplicate... (and that not considering chance of "pleasant" discussion in comments/questions). So I find it hard to recommend spending time on search for duplicates...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: What is that ~30-40 rep based on? If that's the rep you'd have gotten from answering it instead of closing it, sure, but other than that?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes - answer instead of searching + closing or answer other question instead of searching for good duplicate.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: And the rep you get is more valuable than closing something you _know_ is a duplicate?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think that dilemma already discussed plenty on Meta - should one vote duplicate when it is harder than answer  (no downside) and has zero rewards associated. I'm personally all for finding duplicates, but I feel that I should not *recommend*  that to others as there is no support from SE for that (maybe suggest to consider finding duplicates, but ...).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: ___Always___ close to vote as duplicate.  But I guess that explains why upu have over 70k rep.

Comment: @Cerbrus indeed - I agree that this is very low number... I still can't convenience myself to start answering clear duplicates to get rep instead.

Answer (score 37):

I took a look at how the flags were handled.

First of all, the comments you posted on the question were handled automatically; they are all marked as deleted by the Community user. At no point did anyone clean up your comments but deliberately left the OPs comments in place. Note that the only comments you left that were deleted like this were:

- > Possible duplicate of [Getting the class name of an instance in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510972/getting-the-class-name-of-an-instance-in-python)
- > Not everything has a name. For things that do, `__name__`. The duplicate is appropriate. Additionally, as @BartFriederichs implies, this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) at best and not useful at worst.

The first was auto-deleted when you hammered the post, the second when Bhargav re-hammered it (as it [contains the word *duplicate* and a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195654/140890)).

Next, I don't think the OP was particularly abusive towards you, certainly not at the time your comment flag was handled. They were clearly getting a little too attached to the post, but it never got personal. This is why probably why your comment flag was rejected (it wasn't me but I agree with the rejection there).

When you dupe-hammer, users get upset from time to time. Don't let it get to you.

I've cleaned up the comment thread; feel free to flag anything as non-constructive of what remains, but I don't think there is anything left there now but a brief summary of why the post ended up in the current state.

Comment: _"which may or may not be a bug"_ - it is, and an old one at that. Any comment containing the string "duplicate" and any link to an SE domain, or a link to the duplicate target gets auto-deleted when a question is closed as a duplicate, regardless of whether that comment was auto-generated as a result of a duplicate close-vote or whether it was edited. Source: [1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141414/dont-delete-comments-with-link-to-duplicate-if-they-are-modified), [2](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46799/)

Comment: @CodeCaster: ah, of course, yes, the ole 'duplicate' comment remover. I was looking for hints in the URL in the comment. :-)

Answer (score 11):

Without the comments that have been removed, it's pretty difficult to determine what happened there, not to mention if anyone was out of line.

The comments as they are right now are fine. The OP isn't *"flipping his lid"*, and the question is closed as a dupe.

My advice? **Move on.**

There's not namecalling, no swearing, no harsh language. The OP just states that the current target is better than the one you selected.

---

That all said,

Answering a load of dupes just because this dupe closure didn't go the way you wanted is not done.

## <sub>[Don't answer questions that have already been answered elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/)</sub>

Answer (score -4):

> After that, I browsed my tag of choice and answered a bunch of easy
>   questions that I probably could have dupehammered given varying
>   degrees of dupe research. Instead of getting yelled at, getting a flag
>   declined, and having my comments nuked, I rep capped and enjoyed some
>   appreciative comments

Welcome to the real world. There are people here with 10x the rep that you have and 15x the rep that I have, who happily answer questions that should clearly be marked as dupe or closed as too broad and collect lots and lots of points each and every day. Why shouldn't you?

Comment: _"There are people making millions selling drugs. Why shouldn't you?"_ Because then you'd be lowering your standards, to say the least.

Comment: @Cerbrus As long as you don't feel guilty ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That is one heck of an accusation.  Only 43 SO users qualify for 10x rep, 17 of them stopped posting completely, 13 scaled it down to a trickle.  Leaves 13 that could *possibly* match your characterization.  I don't know all of them since they post to tags I don't visit, but they are fine upstanding citizens that never draw complaints and have never been accused of *anything* before.

Comment: @HansPassant if you look at my own behaviour you will see I am one hell of a downvoter and close flagger. Maybe 10x is an exaggeration, but defintiely in my favourite tags the top rep users are doing just this.

Comment: @HansPassant: I know of a couple high rep (>50k) users that'd rather answer a question, than close it as a dupe. Obvious dupes are easy rep: Easy answers, and a lot of people recognize it for being the correct answer.

Comment: Stated differently, the system is constructed to make answering questions a heckuva lot easier than finding duplicates, so lots of people are just lazy. I work very hard to find duplicates, and have received a large number of nasty comments in response. If I cared, I probably would have significantly curtailed my exertions to find duplicates.

Comment: thank you @CodyGray even this answer isn't very popular for the same reason.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can make millions selling drugs? Looks like it's time for a change of profession.